# How to handle Random UnhandledAlertException in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, modal-dialog

When running my testscripts, sometimes an UnhandledAlertException appears. The problem is that the Alert is totally random and I have no way of knowing when it's going to appear.

I need to know what the alert says, so this can be fixed. But selenium dismis the alert the moment it appears.

Can someone tell me how to handle such an alert, so that i can see what the alert says?

Comment: Can we see some code, what have you tried?

Comment: PocketDew's answer does exactly what I want. the alert was about AJAX, webDriver is probably to fast for the AJAX script, so it's giving an alert message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the exception and then handle the alert, by either accepting, dismissing, or getting the text of the alert.

For a C# example:

```cs
try 
{
    // Code that is sometimes throwing the exception.
}
catch (UnhandledAlertException)
{
    IAlert alert = webDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    Console.WriteLine(alert.Text);
}
```

Also, you didn't specify which browser you're using, but if it is Internet Explorer, then look at the InternetExplorerOptions class, which provides an option for specifying the default way you want to handle alerts.